# How to create multiple select drop-down check-box in Google Sheets/Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to make a drop-down list in Google sheets, but the problem is I want multiple select feature in that dropdown. The checkbox feature available in Google sheet is only single select. I've searched a lot but all the available solutions consist creating a extra menu, but I want it to be multiple select checkbox in a dropdown.

Comment: Take a look at this: [multiple select drop downs](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/hot-off-the-presses/multiple-dependent-drop-downs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible. You would have to write an add-on/sidebar that would let users select item(s) and then save values to the cell.